# Usage of javascriptRouter in Play 2.0.2

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have an app which I am trying to upgrade to Play 2.0.2 (from Play 2.0.1). I have this piece of code which worked on Play 2.0.1 but doesn't anymore

```
@javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
 routes.javascript.Contacts.invite,
 routes.javascript.Contacts.remove
)
```

The compiler complains:

```
[error] /myprojectdir/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/views/html/Contacts/list.template.scala:75: Cannot find any HTTP Request Header here
[error] """),_display_(Seq[Any](/*41.2*/javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
[error]                                                             ^
[error] one error found
[error] {file:/myprojectdir/}projectname/compile:compile: Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed 11.07.2012 11:38:51
```

This has been noticed on the mailinglist, and one user has [fixed the problem](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/Z97GQ2VnR5M/XLzkcRykTrUJ). I get that there is some implicit parameter that needs to be passed, but I have no idea how to do this. I tried adding(?) this to my template according to the mentioned [example file](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/db5d40b81f3599ebb6f31e63fbba03d480c0d62c/samples/workinprogress/akka-chat/app/views/room.scala.html), basically changing my templates first line from

```
@(currentUser: User, inviteForm: Form[controllers.Contacts.InviteForm])
```

to

```
@(currentUser: User, inviteForm: Form[controllers.Contacts.InviteForm])(implicit request: RequestHeader)
```

But this seems to change the type signature of the template(?), which is not quite what I would like to happen.

Any suggestions? Everything with (?) is stuff I am not entirely sure of. I've worked with some implicit conversions in Scala before, but I am not sure what Play expects of me here and if I am making a scala or play mistake.

EDIT: There is a corresponding ticket in [the bugtracker](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/581-21-snapshot-jsroutes-missing-implicit-http-request-headers).

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should do. Note that in your controller you could simply update from

```
def foo() = Action {
    ...
    Ok(views.html.contact.list())
}
```

to

```
def foo() = Action { implicit request =>
    ...
    Ok(views.html.contact.list())
}
```

Comment: What can I do from the View? I am using Java controllers, so doing anything implicit won't work there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java controllers you should use the java javascript routing method.
See [this part of the java guide](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaGuide6)

Mixing both languages is fine, but for the routing you should stick to the language style of the controller. Another option is to write a separate scala controller and call those methods.